# PHP page generation timer is returning really high numbers? (1billion+ seconds apparently)

Tags: php, timer

In my PHP project I'm trying to time page generation. Using the script from http://blog.alastair.pro/2013/01/18/php-page-generation-time/ I have created a function that I am calling in footer.php and other miscellaneous PHP files that don't have a footer. As far as I'm aware, this should work:

```
function timer($type)
{
    $totalTime = round((microtime(TRUE) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']), 4);

    if (is_int($type)) {
        if ($type == TYPE_TIMER_COMMENT) {
            return "<!-- Page generated in " . $totalTime . " seconds. -->";
        } elseif ($type == TYPE_TIMER_PLAINTEXT) {
            return "Page generated in " . $totalTime . " seconds.";
        }
    } else {
        header('location:./error/type.html');
        die();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't. It outputs huge numbers:

> Page generated in 1428979311.8916 seconds.
>
> Page generated in 1428979357.1691 seconds.
>
> Page generated in 1428979346.8255 seconds.

etc etc

I have absolutely no idea what's happening here. I'm calling it like so:

```
if (Config::DEBUG)
    echo ('<small>' . timer(TYPE_TIMER_PLAINTEXT) . '</small>');
```

TYPE_TIMER_PLAINTEXT and TYPE_TIMER_COMMENT are consts declared inside of functions.php, but I don't see how this could affect what the function is doing. Any ideas on what's happening here?

Comment: microtime = microseconds https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=1428979311+microseconds+to+seconds

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: @Don'tPanic PHP 5.3.3. I see the problem. I fixed it by updating to 5.4.4. Thank you!

Comment: @bassxzero although the issue has been resolved, 1428.98 seconds is still a ridiculous and incorrect number.

Comment: You're welcome!. I would also recommend changing the error reporting setting in your development environment. A `Notice: Undefined Index` for that missing `$_SERVER` variable would have helped you.

Comment: @nickyschlobs it depends what your script does. I have plenty of PHP scripts that dump 1000's of rows into a .xlsx file and it takes around 15 mins. However, I could see how in this instance you're expecting something considerably lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers you're getting look a lot like numbers you would get from `microtime(true) - 0`. This implies `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] = 0` (or at least something that acts like zero when you subtract it.)

Based on [this note in the PHP documentation for microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php#example-2499), I assume your PHP version is < 5.4, and 'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' is not present in $_SERVER. If your PHP version is >=5.4, then I agree it looks like it should be working.

> As of PHP 5.4.0, REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT is available in the $_SERVER superglobal array. It contains the timestamp of the start of the request with microsecond precision.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I fixed the problem by updating my PHP to something newer than 5.4.0. The $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] was only introduced in 5.4.0, so having PHP 5.3.3 created the issue.